# Why SOLR has a schema and ElasticSearch does not?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

We were comparing those search solutions and started to wonder why one does need a schema and the other does not. What are tradeoffs? Is it because one is like SQL and the other is like NoSQL in sense of schema configuration?

Comment: I just want to point out that both are using Lucene for indexing documents. There should be no difference in how they are stored. You got your answer already, but maybe this information helps for the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

ES does have a schema defined as [templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) and [mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html). You don't have to use it, but in practice you will. Schema is actually a good thing, and if you notice a database claiming to be pure schemaless - there will be performance implication.

Schema is a tradeoff between ease of developing and adoption against performance. It is easy to read/write into a schemaless database, but it it will be less performant, particularly for any non-trivial query.

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch definitely has a schema. If you think it does not, try indexing a date into a field and then an int into the same field. Or even into different types with the same name (I think ES 2.0 disallows that now).

What Elasticsearch does is simplifies auto-creation of a schema. That has tradeoffs such as possible incorrect type detection, fields that are single-valued or multivalued in the result output based on number of elements they contain (they are always multivalued under the covers), and so on. Elasticsearch has some ways to work around that, mostly by defining some of the schema elements and explicit schema mapping as Oleksii wrote.

Solr also has schemaless mode that closely matches Elasticsearch mode, down to storing all JSON as a single field. And when you enable it, you get both similar benefits and similar disadvantages Elasticsearch has. Except, in Solr, you can change things like order of auto-type strategies and mapping to field types. In Elasticsearch (1.x at least) it was hard coded. You can see - slightly dated - comparison in [my presentation from 2014](http://www.slideshare.net/arafalov/solr-vs-elasticsearch-case-by-case).

As Slomo said, they both use Lucene underneath for storing and most of the search. So, the core engine approach cannot change.

Comment: There is one more thing to it: I was looking through the source code and for ES - it is just cleaner, with new technologies, better support for clustering on  AWS and other cloud computing providers, etc.

Comment: Well, of course, you are seeing an Innovator's Dilemma in action. ES came in later and implemented a small subset of Solr functionality based on the latest Lucene. If you only need what ES offers, go for it. Just make sure you are reading 2.0 specs, as things were dropped. As to scaling, Solr is what's running Apple CloudSearch and Bloomberg.